# Find the coefficient of $x^2$ in Taylor's expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be thrice differentiable function on $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ such that $f'(x)= 1+(f(x))^2$.

If $f(0)=1$, then the coefficient of $x^2$ in Taylor's expansion of $f$ about $0$ is?

Comment: for a polynomial the expansion is the polynomial itself. Thus the coefficient is 1.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$
f''(x)=2f'(x)f(x)
$$
by the chain rule. Also, $f'(0)=1+(f(0))^2=2$, so
$$
f''(0)=2\cdot2\cdot1=4
$$

Comment: On the other hand, the solution of the Cauchy problem $y'=1+y^2$, $y(0)=1$ cannot be a function defined over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: what do you mean by this? The solution is clearly $\tan(x+\pi / 4)$... Are you referring to the discontinuity at $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Right so. Is there a solution that is differentiable over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$? I think not.